# Setting edges in proof environment

Tags: beamer, indentation

I would need to move the `itemize` environment used in the `proof` environment more to the left side of every slide. I used `\setbeamersize{text margin left=15pt,text margin right=20pt}` for moving the `definition` and `theorem` environments but what can I use for `itemize` items in the `proof` environment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `leftmargini`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Boadilla}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{proof}
\setlength\leftmargini{10pt}
\begin{itemize}
\item First item.
\item Second item.
\item Third item.
\end{itemize}
\end{proof}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]